# How do I set all GitHub repositories private with one command?

Tags: github

Is it possible to set all repositories from public to private with one command?

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted so much (it may be a duplicate but if so, just close it as a duplicate...). But it's specific to GitHub, so I snipped the [tag:git] tag.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli):

- Fetch all repos currently not private
- Update each repo to private

Something like this:

```bash
gh repo list OWNER --json nameWithOwner,isPrivate \
    --jq 'map(select(.isPrivate | not)) | .[].nameWithOwner'
```

where `OWNER` is the username or the organization whose repositories you want to update. If there are more than 30 repositories, you have to fetch them with an additional `--limit` option, for example `gh repo list OWNER --limit 300`.

The output is a list formatted like

```
OWNER/repo1
OWNER/repo2
```

each of which we can updated like this:

```bash
gh repo edit OWNER/repo1 --visibility private
```

In a single command:

```bash
gh repo list OWNER --json nameWithOwner,isPrivate \
    --jq 'map(select(.isPrivate | not)) | .[].nameWithOwner' \
    | while IFS= read -r repo; do
        gh repo edit "$repo" --visibility private
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

To list all of your public repositories:

```
 curl --request GET https://api.github.com/users/testUser/repos
```

To set a repository of user to private :

```
curl -u testUser:TOKEN --data "{\"private\": \"true\"}" --request PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/testUser/testRepo
```

To set all repositories owned by user to private :

```
curl --request GET https://api.github.com/users/testUser/repos | jq --raw-output '.[] .name' |  xargs -I % curl -u testUser:TOKEN --data "{\"private\": \"true\"}" --request PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/abc/%
```

**Info:**

- Replace `testUser` everywhere with your username on GitHub.
- Replace `TOKEN` with your personal access token for command line. To generate a Token follow [link](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)
- `jq` can be installed from this [link](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
- `curl` util can be downloaded from this [link](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)